# Curses - endwin is resetting to original terminal size after the terminal has been resized

Tags: curses, terminal.app

I have a Curses application that is running ok. It handles resizing the term well and everything draws ok. The only problem is that when `endwin()` is called it resets the terminal to the original size. IE, I'm using the application, I resize my term, I quit the application, my term goes back to the original size.

What do i need to do to prevent this?

Thanks.

Comment: Ok so i figured out what was happening. The problem was with my terminal, not my Curses application. The terminal (Apples Terminal program) supports tabs. When the application would exit the Terminal was resizing itself to the size of Tab 1. Pulling the application tab out into its own window or setting it as tab one fixes the problem. Thanks to everyone who gave me their time.

Comment: You should put that in an answer and accept it.